# Ambari Server Ldap User login issue

Tags: hadoop, ldap, bigdata, ambari

Hi Iam using Ambari version 2.7.3. I have integrated with LDap . I can see all users and groups from LDAP  in ambari. and i given admin permissions for users & i have given Cluster Administrator permissions for Groups also.

But Iam unable to login into ambari using those users. Iam getting below error

```
[ambari-client-thread-21185] AmbariAuthenticationEventHandlerImpl:136 - Failed to authenticate username (attempt #1): Unable to sign in. Invalid username/password combination.
```

The usernae and password from LDAp is correct . I have configured the same LDap to my other applications and those are working fine.

For Ambari only I am facing this issue.

Comment: This is **generic error**, to see the actual cause **tailf** ambari-server.log and try to login again. You will get the real time logs paste them here.

Comment: INFO [ambari-client-thread-21449] AmbariAuthenticationEventHandlerImpl:136 - Failed to authenticate "user" (attempt #5): Unable to sign in. Invalid username/password combination

Answer (score 0):

After I restart Ambari-server , All the users from Ldap are login into ambari now.